How do I snap together bones from different armatures?
I’ve been wondering How do I snap together bones from different armatures.
I saw this guy modsomefun, do it so smooth and I can’t find a tutorial anywhere on how to do it.


Just enable vertex snapping, maybe with "align rot to target" option.
When the snapping is set, you can temporarily toggle between snapping enabled or disabled using CTRL key, so probably the guy is pressing G, then CTRL clicking on the target location.

